# What is "Simplified JavaScript"?

Tags: javascript

Douglas Crockford makes reference to **Simplified JavaScript** in this article about [**Top Down Operator Precedence**](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html).  Unfortunately he only makes references to it in this article.  The best explanation I found [**here**](http://patricklogan.blogspot.com/2007/10/simplified-javascript-cruft-reduced.html).  But I still don't have a clue what it actually is.

**What is Simplified JavaScript?**

Comment: "Simplified JavaScript" - is that when you comment all of it out?  ;)

Comment: jondavidjohn - That's outright stupid. It's like calling heat and light the best of the sun and declaring radiation, interference, gravity etc, a side effects that should be removed. In other words, jQuery can't function without JS, and there isn't any part of JS which jQuery just needs to run.

Comment: @Christian: I see someone's sarcasm detector is broken.

Comment: good grief man, it was a joke, chill out.

Comment: Bah! It's 3am here and I ain't got no time for sarcasm :D. On a further thought, doesn't seem like I'm the only one. Anyway, +1 for the good joke :)

Comment: are you being funny now? ...  I'm so confused.

Comment: Well, you asked for it (re: "chill out")

Comment: jQuery doesn't simplify JavaScript, though. It simplifies working with the DOM.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: I think the issue is that there's a lot of jQuery fanboyism (if you'll allow the word) that happens around here, and it can get tedious, so it's hard to tell when someone is joking. I, for one, thought you were serious at first. Glad to see you weren't :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of the Top Down Operator Precedence article, "simplified" means "easier to write a parser for". That is, he wanted to demonstrate how to write a Javascript parser in Javascript, without overcomplicating things by trying to support all the full specfications loveable quirks.

Yes, the features supported in "Simplified Javascript" are very close to those listed as "Good Parts", but the point of that article was not to promote Crockford's world view or book, but to show how to write a language parser (no easy task).

From the article:

> We don't have time in this short
>   chapter to deal with the whole
>   JavaScript language, and perhaps we
>   wouldn't want to because the language
>   is a mess. But it has some brilliant
>   stuff in it that is well worth
>   consideration. We will build a parser
>   that can process Simplified
>   JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a reference to Crockford's book [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). In this book, he describes which features of Javascript he feels are "good", as well as those that are "bad" and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Crockford's texts are quite disappointing in the sense that he presents real issues and answers but on the next page ridicules his motives by exaggeration. Best example? `Eval`. It's been used badly countless times, but that doesn't make it any less useful. It has it's place in coding. Same as the `with` statement, which helped me out in a very tight spot some months ago.
Back to the discussion, simplified javascript. It is nothing less that what Crockford thinks that is the drive behind javascript - mind you, I do agree with certain aspects, but it's subjective and he doesn't admit it.

Comment: @Christian Crockford is a simple guy. If a certain feature may lead to bad results, it's simpler to ban it entirely, than to define the scenarios where it may and may not be used. If you don't agree with this minimalistic approach, then... you just don't agree with it. But it's not fair to label someone else's work as "disappointing" just because you don't agree with that person's approach.

Comment: @Šime - With that approach one would arguably restrict javascript to a handful of functions. You can't just ban something just because it might be abused. I think "disappointing" is fair enough - people don't usually start a fair argument and shoot their feet halfway through.

Comment: @Christian Crockford's restrictions are minor: eval operator, with statement, `==` and `!=` operators, void operator, continue statement, and a few other things. More than 95% of the language stays intact.

Comment: He also does not like `++` or `--` operators because they encourage "tricky" code or something...so yea, banned. That's how he rolls, demonstrates one or two ways in which a feature can be abused, then demands it completely be excised from the language based on nothing else. You can ignore his recommendations for now, but do know that EMCAScript 5's "strict mode" will throw a SyntaxError if it sees any `with` or `eval` statements. This is because of Crockford alone, and if he continues to get his way version 6 will have them, and other features he disapproves of removed in totality. Nerdrage!

Comment: @MooGoo LOL I think you're giving him too much credit :) He's just a guy that works for Yahoo. The standardization process of ECMAScript includes people from various companies. The direction that ECMAScript is taking just happens to concord with Crockfords opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified JavaScript is not quite a language (yet), but it could be. There is Pratt's/Crockford's Simplified Parser [TDOP](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/index.html), and that is a first step, but you would need either a code generator or an interpretor to process the parser's output "tree" into working JavaScript. IMHO that will be a good thing. Then an IDE that would help anyone learn and write this proposed language "Simplified JavaScript", will follow.